# How can i run commands in iex from a script?

Tags: bash, shell, elixir

I'm trying to write a simple script that starts different nodes of IEX, each with it's name, and want this nodes to execute de Node.ping :node_name@hostname but I didn't find anything.

This is the script i have for the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Opens 3 clients

gnome-terminal  --command="bash -c 'iex --sname client1; $SHELL'"
gnome-terminal  --command="bash -c 'iex --sname client2; $SHELL'"
gnome-terminal  --command="bash -c 'iex --sname client3; $SHELL'"

#Opens de server
gnome-terminal  --command="bash -c 'iex --sname server; $SHELL'"
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear; maybe you could rewrite it to explain better what you see as an expected scenario in the end?

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to start a certain amount of client nodes and 1 server node, connect them all and then execute a code i've written for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot “pipe” commands to `iex` or send it to the running instance in any other way, but luckily enough, one might take advantage of using [`.iex.exs`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) file.

Create a directory, create an `.iex.exs` in it with any content you want and run your script from within it.

---

Please note, that one needs first to call [`Node.connect/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#connect/1) for [`Node.ping/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#ping/1) to succeed after.

Comment: Would iex -S mix --sname client1 etc be an option?